# Calling NSLayoutConstraint's subclass'c constant variable

Tags: ios, subclass, swift4, nslayoutconstraint

I have created a custom class of `NSLayoutConstraint`. I have to update a top constraint's constant value depending on the iOS Version. But the constant variable of `NSLayoutConstraint` is not getting called anyways. I have tried so many ways but it is not getting called. Below is my code for NSLayoutConstraint's custom class:

```
override var constant: CGFloat {
    set {
        super.constant = newValue
    }
    get {
        return topConstraintConstant()
    }
}

fileprivate func topConstraintConstant() -> CGFloat {
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        return 0
    }else {
        return -20
    }
}
```

I have created an IBOutlet of TableView's top constraint and assigned custom class to it.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have overwritten the property constant uncleanly in your code above. If you assign a value to `constant` your implementation may return a different value. Further you **cannot** know if `NSLayoutConstraint` uses the getter or the ivar to access the value of `constant`. Overwriting properties of foreign classes is very unsafe, especially if they are from Apple.

Subclassing `NSLayoutConstraint` shouldn't be necessary here. You should do this in very rare cases. You can work with ordinary constraints. If your constraint outlet variable is `topConstraint`you may use

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, * ) {
    topConstraint.constant = 0.0
}
else {
    topConstraint.constant = -20.0
}
```

in `viewDidLoad`.

BTW: Using fixed values for the status bar is a code smell. Use the appropriate layout guides like `safeAreaLayoutGuide`, `topLayoutGuide` etc. instead.

Comment: Yes. I know that above code is working fine. But I just wanted to know how it works. and I have tried using both `safeAreaLayoutGuide` and `topLayoutGuide` but nothing works for me. So I have decided to do this kind of stuff.

Comment: I've extended my answer.